# Is there a way to tweak this code so that it underlines multiple lines of text?

Tags: html, css, underline

```css
#full-service-creative-studio::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 103%;
  height: 28px;
  background: #46989C;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="full-service-creative-studio">Full Service Design Studio</h1>
```

Currently, it works great for a single line but when we scale down to say mobile view it only underlines the bottom line of the text. Is there a way to make every line underlined?

Comment: Your code in the question currently doesn't underline anything. Please edit it to add a [mre].

Comment: You have `id="full-service-design-studio"` but in your `css` you are selecting `#full-service-creative-studio`. You need to select the correct `id` in your snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#full-service-design-studio {
  
  text-decoration: underline  #46989C;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="full-service-design-studio">Full Service Design Studio</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
#full-service-creative-studio{
   text-decoration: underline  #46989C;
}
```

The pseudo selector `::after` will put the line underneath the `h1` `ELEMENT_NODE` and not the `TEXT_NODE` contained within the `h1` element.

Answer (score 0):

You need is a css class

```
.underline
{
   text-decoration: underline  #46989C;
}
```

currently, you are using an `id` selector to apply the css that is why it is only applying to a single line, using a `class` as a selector you can apply the same style to multiple elements.

Crux is that CSS `id` selector is used to find only 1 element. while `classes` are used to apply common styles across various HTML tags.

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline #46989C;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="underline">Line 1</h1>
<h2 class="underline"> Line 2</h2>
<h3 class="underline">Line 3</h3>
<p class="underline"> Line 4</p>
```

Hope this [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) link helps you understand

Comment: This is wrong. Your code is selecting the `.underline::after` element. There is no text to underline in the `::after` element.

Comment: oh may bad... updating the answer... just remove the `:after` from the class

Comment: The id selector isn't the problem - there's only one element being selected, and that's fine.

Comment: i believe that classes are the best way to handle the styles, especially when you are working with multiple screen sizes. this is my personal take, you may / can use the `id` selectors as well

Answer (score 0):

The hardest part (which every other answer ignores) is the `left` offset you have on the underline element, as well as the `103%` length.

You can use a data-attribute, pseudo element, `text-decoration` and `text-underline-offset` to handle this.

These are not perfect by any means, but gets you kind of close - and may give you an idea.

The title says "tweak code", so this adds a `data-attribute` to the `H1` tag with the same title content. We then style the `::after` pseudo with everything to push the line left. The problem with this, is that at certain breakpoints the pseudo element will wrap before the visible text, creating a hanging underline.

I don't think you can get this right, unless the whole underline can be left of the content (see the second example) - which again, gets close:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2.2;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1::after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: transparent;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: underline #46989C 28px;
  text-underline-offset: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

/* makes pseudo text a little smaller to try and prevent wrapping */
h1.small::after {
  font-size: 99%;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-content="Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio ull Service Design Studio &nbsp;&nbsp;">Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio</h1>


<h1 data-content="Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio ull Service Design Studio &nbsp;&nbsp;" class="small">Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio</h1>
```

### Number 2

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2.2;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1::after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: transparent;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: underline #46989C 28px;
  text-underline-offset: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-content="Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio ull Service Design Studio">Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio Full Service Design Studio</h1>
```